# Is there a code to perform coreference resolution in AllenNLP in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, allennlp, coreference-resolution

Is there a code to perform coreference resolution in AllenNLP in Python?

The existing code samples on the internet don't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you seen https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution? Check out the "Model Usage" tab on that page.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like petew mentioned in the comment, sample code is in the [demo page here](http://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution)